# scrapy with newline characters and nested tags

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing, scrapy

Disclaimer: new to scrapy.

I have a table with pretty irregular rows, The basic structure is:

```
<tr>
 <td> some text </td>
 <td> some other text </td>
 <td> yet some text </td>
</tr>
```

but occasionally (a few hundred times) some rows are

```
<tr>
 <td> <p> some text <p> </td>
 <td> <div class="class-whateva"> <p> some other text </p></div> </td>
 <td> <span id="strange-id"> 
  <a href="somelink"> yet some text </a> 
    <span> </td>
</tr>
```

or other permutations of 1 or 2 nested "p" "div" and "span" with or without return line characters.

I've taken care of the nested "span span" or "p div" or "div span" with conditional statements of the form:

```
for row in allrows:
      if  row.select('td[2]/text()'):
            item['seconditem']=row.select('td[2]/text()').extract()
      elif row.select('td[2]/*/text()'):
            item['seconditem']=row.select('td[2]/*/text()').extract()
      elif row.select('td[2]/*/*/text()'):
            item['seconditem']=row.select('td[2]/*/*/text()').extract()
```

Now I have two questions:

(1)  Is conditional

```
td[2]/*/*/text()
```

the right way to go about for irregular nested rows?

(2) I am still missing all the cases where there is a return (or newline) before the tag.
So if the row is of the form:

```
   <td><div>
      <p>text </p>
   </div></td>
```

All my xpath will return is a ['\n     '].  Any trick to catch what's after the newline character?

Any tips appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string()` function in `XPath` expression to get all inner text nodes in one string:

```python
# nested.html - your second html snippet
# $scrapy shell "nested.html" 

In [1]: row = hxs.select('//tr')

In [2]: row.select('td[2]').select('string()').extract()
Out[2]: [u'   some other text  ']

In [3]: row.select('td[2]').select('string()').extract()[0]
Out[3]: u'   some other text  '

In [4]: row.select('td[3]').select('string()').extract()[0]
Out[4]: u'  \r\n   yet some text  \r\n     '
```

Or `//text()` to get all inner `text` nodes:

```python
In [5]: row.select('td[3]//text()').extract()
Out[5]: [u' \r\n  ', u' yet some text ', u' \r\n    ', u' ']
```

And `''.join(...)` to get string:

```python
In [6]: ''.join(row.select('td[3]//text()').extract())
Out[6]: u' \r\n   yet some text  \r\n     '
```

Comment: thanks reclosedev. I didn't know about select('string()'). It works like charm.

Comment: @reclosedev can you help in this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915573/how-to-extract-li-element-using-xpath-and-put-each-and-every-one-in-a-separate