# How to extract <li> element using xpath and put each and every one in a separate new line

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying extract all text from a given html segment using xpath 
Here is html code snap

```
        <div class="grid-block sub-list">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/music-system-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Music System Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Music System Dealers</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/projector-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Projector Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Projector Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/satellite-tv-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Satellite TV Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Satellite TV Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/tv-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="TV Dealers in Visakhapatnam">TV Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/bean-bags-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Bean Bag Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Bean Bag Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/epabx-pbx-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="EPABX Dealers in Visakhapatnam">EPABX Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/generators-sales_visakhapatnam" title="Generators Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Generators Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/industrial-voltage-stabilizer-manufacturers_visakhapatnam" title="Industrial Voltage Stabilizers Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Industrial Voltage Stabilizers Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/online-ups-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Online UPS Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Online UPS Dealers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yellowpages.sulekha.com/photocopier-dealers_visakhapatnam" title="Photocopier Dealers in Visakhapatnam">Photocopier Dealers</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here out i am able to get right now

```
Music System DealersProjector DealersSatellite TV DealersTV DealersBean Bag DealersEPABX DealersGenerators DealersIndustrial Voltage Stabilizers DealersOnline UPS DealersPhotocopier Dealers
```

Expected out put should be

```
Music System Dealers
Projector Dealers
Satellite TV Dealers
TV DealersBean Bag Dealers
EPABX Dealers
Generators Dealers
Industrial Voltage Stabilizers Dealers
Online UPS Dealers
Photocopier Dealers
```

Here is how i am trying extract

```
"".join(response.xpath('//body//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()').extract()
```

Any one can help me to get expected output

Comment: @paultrmbrth Hi Paul, Can you guide me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

add some css like

```
.sub-list li{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: I have collected millions of html pages from all over web by scrapy crawler.So i can't modify css part.Is there any way to get it done using xpath or any other way ?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @Lalji Tadhani I am extracting text in a text file.